# In what case can we describe forces by potential?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy, conservative-field

Let's consider a particle in an $N$-dimensional space and let's assume that acceleration of this particle depends on its position. So, one can say that we have an $N$-dimensional vector field in an $N$-dimensional space (a mapping from position to acceleration)

What allows us describe this "acceleration field" as gradient of some potential?

Should dependency of acceleration on position have a special form to make it possible to introduce a potential?

Answer (score 2):

If the force at $\vec r$, $\vec F(\vec r)$, is the gradient of a potential i.e. $\vec F = - \nabla \phi$ then $\nabla \times \vec F=0$. And vice versa, if the curl of $\vec F$ is zero everywhere then there is a potential field $\phi( \vec r)$ such that $F= -\nabla \phi$. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If a force ${\bf F}=\sum_{i=1}^N F_{i}({\bf x})\mathrm{d}x^i$ is given as a co-vector field/1-form on an $N$-dimensional manifold, then [Poincare Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) states that there exists locally a potential $V({\bf x})$ such ${\bf F}=-\mathrm{d}V$ if and only if the 1-form ${\bf F}$ is closed $\mathrm{d}{\bf F}=0$.